# Jest ignoring CI environment variable

Tags: javascript, jestjs, github-actions

I am confusing something, or Jest should disable watch mode when running in a CI environment?

I am using github actions and the `CI` environment variable is set to `true`

My `package.json` has the entry `test`

```json
"scripts": {
  "test": "firebase emulators:exec --only firestore --project sample 'jest --runInBand --watch'"
}
```

Notice the `--watch`, this make the Jest watch for new tests.

Here is my GitHub action file

```yaml
name: Jest

on: [push, pull_request]

defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: functions

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '12.x'
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm test
```

Because of that, my tests on Actions takes forever, until timeout.

I am missing something? Should Jest ignore the `--watch` flag when running on CI mode?

Comment: *"Should Jest ignore the `--watch` flag when running on CI mode?"* Did you read somewhere that it does that or do you *wish* that it would do that? Why don't you just create another command that runs jest without `--watch`?

Comment: I read somewhere that Jest ignores watch mode on CI. Is it correct?

Comment: I don't know. The documentation says about `--watchAll` (not `--watch`) only: *"Use --watchAll=false to explicitly disable the watch mode. Note that in most CI environments, this is automatically handled for you."* But it doesn't say how that's done.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering what happens if you use file watchers with CI. When using the default NPM test provided by react, there are no issues (they probably check for the CI env variable themselves). If I use `jest --watchAll`.

[image]

The test keeps running. You can simply use different commands. I don't know of an elegant way to have if CI jest else jest `--watchAll` in a single terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

IF you're using jest via CRA (create-react-app) and running via some integration pipeline, then these pipelines typically set CI=true in the environment, in turn making CRA supply different configuration to jest.

So yes, you're likely confused (as am I) since CRA changes things.

And more confusion worth being aware of: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9345